# Sklearn custom kernel gives wrong decision function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, kernel-methods

I have successfully implemented my own custom linear kernel which works totally fine using the **`clf.predict`**. However, when I want to use the **`clf.decision_function`** it gives constant values for all points.

This is the code for the custom kernel:

````
```
def linear_basis(x, y):
    return np.dot(x.T, y)

def linear_kernel(X, Y, K=linear_basis):
    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]))
    for i, x in enumerate(X):
        for j, y in enumerate(Y):
            gram_matrix[i,j] = K(x,y)
        return gram_matrix
```
````

Now using this kernel for a small linear training set.

````
```
#creating random 2D points
sample_size = 100
dat = {
    'x': [random.uniform(-2,2) for i in range(sample_size)],
    'y': [random.uniform(-2,2) for i in range(sample_size)]
}

data = pd.DataFrame(dat)

# giving the random points a linear structure
f_lin = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: 1 if x > y else 0)
data['z_lin'] = f_lin(data['x'].values, data['y'].values)
data_pos = data[data.z_lin == 1.]
data_neg = data[data.z_lin == 0.]

X_train = data[['x', 'y']]
y_train = data[['z_lin']]

clf_custom_lin = svm.SVC(kernel=linear_kernel) # using my custom kernel here
clf_custom_lin.fit(X_train.values,y_train.values)

# creating a 100x100 grid to manually predict each point in 2D
gridpoints = np.array([[i,j] for i in np.linspace(-2,2,100) for j in np.linspace(-2,2,100)])
gridresults = np.array([clf.predict([gridpoints[k]]) for k in range(len(gridpoints))])

# now plotting each point and the training samples
plt.scatter(gridpoints[:,0], gridpoints[:,1], c=gridresults, cmap='RdYlGn')
plt.scatter(data_pos['x'], data_pos['y'], color='green', marker='o', edgecolors='black')
plt.scatter(data_neg['x'], data_neg['y'], color='red', marker='o', edgecolors='black')
plt.show()
```
````

This gives the following result:

[image: Result of the custom linear kernel.]

Now I want to reproduce the plot using `clf.decision_function`:

**(!Note that I accidentally switched the colors here!)**

````
```
h = .02
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-2 - .5, 2 + .5, h),
    np.arange(-2 - .5, 2 + .5, h))

# using the .decision_function here
Z = clf_custom_lin.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]) 

Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, alpha=.8)

plt.scatter(data_pos['x'], data_pos['y'], color='blue', marker='o', edgecolors='black')
plt.scatter(data_neg['x'], data_neg['y'], color='red', marker='o', edgecolors='black')
plt.show()
```
````

This gives the following plot:

[image: Constant predictions of the custom kernel.]

This is an example of a plot of the same data using the integrated linear kernel (kernel="linear"):
[image: Working decision function using the "linear" statement.]

Since the prediction function for the custom kernel just worked, it should give the same working plot with the decision function here, right?
I don't have any idea why this is working with the integrated linear function but not with the custom linear function which also works for just predicting points without the decision function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is really silly, but since it took quite some time to track down, I'll share an outline of my debugging.

First, rather than plotting, print the actual values of the `decision_function`: you'll find that the first one comes out unique, but that after that everything is constant.  Running the same on various slices of the dataset, this pattern persists.  So I thought perhaps some values were being overwritten, and I dug into the `SVC` code a bit.  That lead to some useful internal functions/attributes, like `._BaseLibSVM__Xfit` containing the training data, `_decision_function` and `_dense_decision_function`, and `_compute_kernel`.  But none of the code indicated a problem, and running them just showed the same problem.  Running `_compute_kernel` gave results that were all-zeros past the first row, and then coming back to your code, running `linear_kernel` does that already.  So, finally, it comes back to your `linear_kernel` function.

You return *inside* the outer for loop, so you only ever use the first row of `X`, never computing the rest of the matrix.  (This brings up a surprise: why did the predictions look good?  That seems to have been a fluke.  Changing the definition for `f_lin`, to change the classes, the model still learns the slope-1 line.)

Comment: Ok this is really silly... Thank you so much, I also started looking inside the sklearn source code already, did not realize my custom kernel was wrong in the first place.

Any idea on how to improve the runtime here? Now that the return is at the correct place, the code seems really inefficient.

Comment: The kernel function could just be written as a matrix product, which should shave off some time. I'm not sure what (else) `libsvm` is doing under the hood for efficiency.